# Ubuntu 20.04 dragging "INSTALL" from Eclipse Marketplace to Eclipse icon doesn't work

Tags: firefox, icons, eclipse

I want to download an Eclipse plugin which doesn't appear on Marketplace window, but is on Marketplace website. I am install it by dragging the "install button" from Firefox to Eclipse, but Eclipse window doesn't show when the button is above Eclipse icon. I've also tried drag & drop files from Nautilus to Firefox, and nothing happens too.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is version of Eclipse? How Eclipse was installed?

Comment: Eclipse 2012.12 and Ubuntu 20.04. Eclipse is installed via setup.